# How to toggle or minimize windows using child process.exec module

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

so lets say i run an executable (e.g Sublime Text.exe) from node js via 'child_process'.execFile module

```
var sublime = child(sublimeExePath, function(err, data) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

does node provides any api to hide/minimize/maximize the executable or perform similar actions.

Comment: this is not what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this library: https://github.com/thraaawn/winctl

But, it works only on windows.